# Removing a Pycharm external library

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, ros

Pycharm tries to index an external library of mine called 'ROS', which is for an unknown reason mounted at my root '/'. This causes days of Pycharm trying to index my entire drive.

I have deleted and reinstalled Pycharm with no success.
I have looked at deleting the external library from within the Project interpreter to no avail.

Where would Pycharm be detecting this external library defined as 'ROS', and how can I remove it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: rna]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed?

Comment: @user2235698 Yes but nothing ROS related: rainbow brackets; Bashsupport; CSV plugin; Indent Rainbow; Handlebars/Moustache.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to delete the .idea project files. Usually external libraries is an issue of interpreter paths, but not in this case.

Comment: Thank you.  I deleted `.idea/libraries/ROS.xml` which did the trick without having to delete the entire project.